# Facebook Marketing API Get Campaigns per date

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I have created an application requesting from facebook's Marketing API, to return all my ad accounts, and from all my ad accounts all my ad campaigns, and from all my campaigns, get insights for a specific date(or date range).
Now because my campaigns are too many and I can't make a request for every campaign in a account(even if I wanted the facebook's throttling mechanism kicks in) I am trying to find a way to get only the campaigns that were active or had data on my specific date(date range).

I added the 'time_range' parameter as the link below (Api manual) describes:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/campaigns/

time_range format I use: &time_range={'since':'2016-06-13','until':'2016-06-13'}

But I get exactly the same result. All my campaigns if I set the 'limit' parameter to a high value or 25 campaigns if I don't use a the 'limit' parameter(default paging).
Anyone had any issues with the api before? Or any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you are not using the `time_range` param correctly. Check out this answer: [time range filter on ads endpoint (Facebook API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38959704/time-range-filter-on-ads-endpoint-facebook-api/39476055#39476055)

Comment: I was definetly using it correctly. I submitted a bug report on facebook and they told it will be fixed. I just don't know the status of the issue now. I'll check it again soon