# Facebook get post by ads campaign_id

Tags: facebook, ads

I'm first time here. I can't find any answers in net. My question is about Facebook API.

I have ads campaign_id, can I get all posts which have any connection to this campaign? I try to use boosted_object_id, but, I think this is not right decision. Why? I've read that this field returns all object which have connections with my campaign, but it not a posts only. Don't really understand what this request returns

Answer (score 0):

Try querying Campaign -> Ads -> Creative -> Story ID.

So your call can look something like:

```
act_1234567890/campaigns?fields=ads{creative{effective_object_story_id}}
```

OR

```
act_1234567890/campaigns?fields=ads{creative{object_story_id}}
```

Doc available here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative/

Comment: I have some trouble with this method: I can't take old data. I tried to use options like: time_range [I use it right like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843593/facebook-marketing-api-get-campaigns-per-date) and 'date_present'. But it looks like Facebook API can't parse this arguments. 
What I can do with it?